# Highcharts Point Value Disappearing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using Highcharts I have a scatterplot in which I'm formatting the tooltip.  Im displaying data that compares states and want the tooltip to show the state name.  The name will show in the tooltip on the first hover, but then will be blank on the second hover.

I switched from pointFormat option to pointFormatter so that I could console log values.  It looks like after the first hover the state name property is actually having it's value remove.

```
plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 5
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '',
                pointFormatter: function(){
                    console.log(this); 
                    console.log(this.state); 
                    return "<span>" + this.state; + "</span>"
                }
                // pointFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">{point.state}</span>'
            }
        }
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L0c65rb2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your json , you are using "state"  .. I changed it to a dummy entry "part"  and retried its started working

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/L0c65rb2/2/)

```
     tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '',
                pointFormatter: function(){
                    console.log(this); 
                    console.log(this.state); 
                    return "<span>" + this.part+ "</span>"
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem is that I'm using the property name "state" for my state names.  Highcharts must be using this property name internally.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue